# facet-grid in ggplot, R

Tags: r, facet-grid

I'm trying to plot categorical data using ggplot in which I have two categories for parameter ( C and C+Fe) that I pass facet-grid argument.
here is part of my code:

```
mediagene<-ggplot(ARG)+
geom_boxplot(aes(x = gene, y= RA, fill=type))+
ylab("Relative gene abundance\n copies/ 16s rRNA")+
theme_bw()+
facet_grid(parameter~.,switch="y")+
scale_fill_manual(values=cols)+
labs(fill="Saturation")
```

and here is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKLem.jpg)

now my question is that how I can have only the top graph ( only category C from the parameter)

Comment: You could filter your dataset, e.g. use `dplyr::filter(ARG, parameter == "C")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this without adding additional packages is to use the `subset()` function as in:

```
mediagene<-ggplot(subset(ARG, parameter == 'C'))+
geom_boxplot(aes(x = gene, y= RA, fill=type))+
ylab("Relative gene abundance\n copies/ 16s rRNA")+
theme_bw()+
facet_grid(parameter~.,switch="y")+
scale_fill_manual(values=cols)+
labs(fill="Saturation")
```

Answer (score 0):

As stefan suggests, using `dplyr::filter()` can keep only the rows in your data that match a certain condition.

In this instance, you only want to keep data where `parameter` is `'C'`, so you could do something like the following to keep just this data:

```
ARG %>% 
  filter(
    parameter == 'C'
  )
```

We can then send this data to `ggplot` to plot, by:

```
ARG %>% 
  filter(
    parameter == 'C'
  ) %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = gene, y= RA, fill=type))+
  ylab("Relative gene abundance\n copies/ 16s rRNA")+
  theme_bw()+
  facet_grid(parameter~.,switch="y")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=cols)+
  labs(fill="Saturation")
```

In this case, you will not *need* to use `facet_grid()` anymore, because you should only have one facet anyway. Keeping it will however give you the same box with the heading strip with the `'C'` label though, which might be handy.

Without a sample of your data I can't show an example for you unfortunately.